# Get data from table column and make individual array and 2 dimensional array also using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatable

I have to make an array which is fetching data from a table column one which is a text and 5th is value using jQuery and data is input dynamically. Array size is not fixed, and also need make 2 dimensional array using both column. Actually I have to make a chart so column 1 is giving name and column 2 is giving his ownership and data can be varied in each column. I have tried many code I am sending all but I am not getting anything at all:

```
var nameArray = [];//this should be 1 dimenional containing name as ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5']; 
            var ownArray = new Array();//this should be 1 dimenional containing ownership as  [parseInt(u1), parseInt(u2), parseInt(u3), parseInt(u4), parseInt(u5)];
            var namenown = new Array();//this should be 2 dimensional array containg name and ownership as ['user1', parseInt(u1)], ['user2', parseInt(u2)], ['user3', parseInt(u3)];
            ['user4', parseInt(u4)], ['user5', parseInt(u5)]
            $("#resourceUserDetails tbody tr:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
            nameArray.push($(this).text());
                //(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text();
                //alert($(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text());
                //var names = ['"' + nameArray.join('", "') + '"'];               
            });
            $('#resourceUserDetails tbody tr:nth-child(5)').each(function () {
                ownArray.push($(this).value());
            });
            $.each(nameArray, function (index, value) {
                debugger;
                alert(nameArray[index]);
                debugger;
            });
```

Comment: create a fiddle and attach it here

Comment: `tr:nth-child(1)` selects rows that are first in their parents, not cells

Comment: something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh4xc/1/)